The path template 'X' on the action 'X' in controller 'X' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not found for the segment 'X'
I have been Googling and using Chat GPT and cannot figure out how to get rid of the above warning. Here is my code:
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<MessageViewModel>("Message");

// Define the bound action
// var getTagMessagesAction = builder.EntityType<MessageViewModel>().Collection.Action("GetTagMessages");

// Optionally define parameters for the action
// getTagMessagesAction.Parameter<List<int>>("tagIds");

[Authorize]
[Route("odata")]
public class MessageController : ODataController
{
[HttpPut]
[Route("GetTagMessages")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTagMessages([FromBody] List<int> tagIds)
{
    var messages = await _db.MessageTags.Where(x => tagIds.Any(t => t == x.TagId))
        .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    var mapped = _mapper.Map<List<Message>, List<MessageViewModel>>(messages);
    return Ok(mapped);
}

}

I am calling it with https://localhost:5001/odata/GetTagMessages and passing a list of integers in the body.
The call is successful without configuring the action in the EDM model builder, but I am getting the warning when I run the solution:

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention[0]
The path template 'odata/GetTagMessages' on the action 'GetTagMessages' in controller 'Message' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not found for the segment 'GetTagMessages'.

When I configure the action as I have in the EDM Model Builder, by removing the commented code, I get 405 Method Not Allowed. I try changing to a POST call and still get the same error.
If I remove [Route("odata")] from the controller, and change the route on the endpoint to [Route("~/GetTagMessages")], the warning goes away, but I get the 405 error.
I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, and any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to get a clean build without the warning so that everything is properly configured.

The warning message is expected based on your model schema and controller/action setting. Because, there's no element called 'GetTagMessages' in your model.
If you config the action in the Edm model builder, you get "405" is expected because OData routing builds a 'conventional' endpoint for 'GetTagMessage' controller method.
I create a sample for your reference and make the Edm action working without warning. See details at commit https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/commit/87cfed8981156ab2edde5618cb9f28eb4e6fc057
Please let me know your details requirements. You can file issue on the github or leave the comments here.
Thanks.

Why did you remove the route from the HttpPost attribute? Doesn't that need to be there? Should it be [HttpPost("GetTagMessages")]

Also, on the controller route attribute, I noticed that you removed the [Route("odata")]. Is that ok? I have other controller methods, including additional Post endpoints in that controller. Will removing the odata route attribute change the route for all of my endpoints in that controller, or does it default to odata?

I just want to say thank you. I got it working with your help. I will show my final code.
